# OpenSSL Verify: Difference Between "unable to get issuer certificate" and "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, x.509

From the [man pages](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Verify(1)):

> **2 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT:** unable to get issuer
>   certificate
>
> the issuer certificate of a looked up certificate could not be found. This normally means the list of trusted certificates is not
>   complete.
>
> **20 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY**: unable to get local
>   issuer certificate
>
> the issuer certificate could not be found: this occurs if the issuer certificate of an untrusted certificate cannot be found.

I'm not sure if I get that. For me it sounds both quite the same. What do they mean with "*looked up certificate*" and "*untrusted certificate*". An untrusted certificate would be any certificate along the chain but the root  certificate. A look up certificate could be an externally retreived certificate, like though `AuthoritiyInfoAccess`. But I'm really not certain here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both error cides are very similar. You can view its usage on `crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c` line 432 onwards:

```
if (trust != X509_TRUST_TRUSTED && !bad_chain) {
    if ((chain_ss == NULL) || !ctx->check_issued(ctx, x, chain_ss)) {
        if (ctx->last_untrusted >= num)
            ctx->error = X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY;
        else
            ctx->error = X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT;
        ctx->current_cert = x;
    } else {
        …
    }
    …
 }
```

Thus, the only difference between both error codes is whether `ctx->last_untrusted` was >= `num`  when the untrusted certificate was found.

Here, `num` holds the number of untrusted certs and `last_untrusted` the index of the last untrusted cert.

The condition `last_untrusted >= num` (`X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY`) would be met if a trusted chaing to a certificate in the trust store was not found, whereas `X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT` seem to happen if a CA matched but the chain validation failed anyway, maybe due a malicious chain but perhaps simply due to a missing intermediate.

Comment: Thanks for inspecting the code. For me as a greenhorn that'd probably taken years to find the right spot :) I'm still not sure however, if I understand correctly. So `num ` holds the number of untrusted certs, of the chain, hence all certs but the root cert. `last_untrusted` is the index of the last untrusted certificate of the chain. What would that be? Imagine the server sends you a set of certificates of which you can build two seperate chains and no cert points to a valid root.

Comment: @Hansi I'm not sure to have completely understood it, either. The descriptions of the variable purposes are taken from openssl comments (I wish there were more!). Take my explanation with a grain of salt☺.  `num` is the size of the chain passed to the verify function. If there are two chains, and alternate chain checking wasn't disabled, it tries to find out another path, discarding the other one, see lines 386-425.